# php create url from file path

Tags: php, url, path

let's say that i have folder called `new` inside there's 
file called `index.php` and subfolder called `inc` . sub folder contain `sub.php` file 
my index.php page is

```
$path = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

and my sub.php

```
require('../index.php');
echo $path;
```

the output like that

```
localhost/new/inc/sub.php
```

and i need it like that

```
localhost/new/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please Try this in your file**

```
 <?php
         $path = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `index.php`:

```
$path = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', __DIR__);
```

`__DIR__` will show you the directory that `index.php` is in. From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php):

> The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned.

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` will give the directory of the web root, which is the top-level folder that all your web documents are inside.

`str_replace` removes the latter from the former, giving you the directory inside the web root that `index.php` is in.

Comment: same result nothing change